# Apache HTTP Client 5.3 ~ NTCredentials no longer working

Tags: java, credentials, apache-httpclient-5.x

I have a project that uses `org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5`. I recently tried upgrading from version 5.2.3 to version 5.3, only to realize that the authentication was no longer working in the new version.

Here is how the relevant code looks:

```
        BasicCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider =
            new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(host, port),
            new NTCredentials(username, password.toCharArray(), "", "")
        );
        httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .build();
[...]
            final HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(targetUrl);

            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

Before the update from 5.2.3 to 5.3 this worked fine. However, when I use 5.3, I now get a 401 UNAUTHORIZED response.

I also tried the following variations to above code to pass the credentials along, but they all also return only 401 UNAUTHORIZED:

```
        httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(CredentialsProviderBuilder.create()
                .add(new HttpHost(host, port), username, password.toCharArray())
                .build())
            .build();
```

```
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(host, port),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password.toCharArray())
        );
```

```
        SystemDefaultCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider =
            new SystemDefaultCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(host, port),
            new NTCredentials(username, password.toCharArray(), "", "")
        );
```

Now I am stumped. Could this be a bug in 5.3? Or did something change to the way that the NTCredentialsProvider works? I could not find any release notes indicating so, and since this is only a minor version update that would surprise me.

Nonetheless, the fact it that it works with the old version but not with the new one. Does anyone has any suggestions as to what I can do about that?

Comment: Report an issue to the project?

Comment: As of version 5.3 NTLM has been deprecated and is no longer supported

Comment: @ok2c : I was under the impression that `@Deprecated` marks elements that still work, but are discouraged from using, and which might be removed entirely in future versions. So I my expectation was that it would still work until the next major version update. What is the point of leaving something that no longer works in the code at all? In my understanding, a minor version update should not introduce breaking changes like this.

Comment: @KiraResari NTLM still works as before. One needs to re-enable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We now managed to solve it by providing the `httpclient` with a default auth scheme registry like this:

```
        Lookup<AuthSchemeFactory> authSchemeRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<AuthSchemeFactory>create()
                .register(StandardAuthScheme.NTLM, new NTLMSchemeFactory()).build();

        httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
                .setDefaultAuthSchemeRegistry(authSchemeRegistry)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time trying to get Apache Http Client to authenticate using Single Sign on and Windows Integrated Authentication against a Servlet running on Tomcat with the Waffle filter configured to use Negotiate. My code used to work fine with Apache HttpClient 4.5 but with 5.x it stopped working. This is the code that worked for me.

```
System.out.println("Win auth available: " + WinHttpClients.isWinAuthAvailable());
    if (WinHttpClients.isWinAuthAvailable()) {
        ClassicHttpRequest request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/ssotestwebapp/webapp");
        CloseableHttpClient client = WinHttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
        
        Collection<String> targetPreferedAuthSchemes = Collections.unmodifiableList(
                Arrays.asList(StandardAuthScheme.KERBEROS, StandardAuthScheme.SPNEGO, StandardAuthScheme.NTLM,
                        StandardAuthScheme.BEARER, StandardAuthScheme.DIGEST, StandardAuthScheme.BASIC));
        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setTargetPreferredAuthSchemes(targetPreferedAuthSchemes)
                .build();
        context.setRequestConfig(config);
        
        client.execute(request, context, response -> {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(new StatusLine(response));
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String s = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            System.out.println(s);
            EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
            return null;
        });
    }
```

Createing a custom RequestConfig and list of targetPreferedAuthSchemes is the important part beacause the default RequestConfigs doesn't contain the deprecated schemes and will not use them even if you add them to the AuthSchemes reqistry.

Here are the maven dependencies i used:

```
<!--
    https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents.client5/httpclient5 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
    https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents.client5/httpclient5-win -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient5-win</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This is the way to go for those who are still stuck with NTLM authentication.